# How to loop through localstorage with array in it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

How do I loop through the below localstorage and and then write it out in my array?

The localstorage looks like this:

```
{"data":[[0,"Post1","Text1","2016-12-16T11:01:00.000Z"],[1,"Post2","Text2","2016-12-20T14:00:00.000Z"]],[3,"Post3","Text3","2016-12-25T13:00:00.000Z"]]}
```

And I can read from it like this:

```
info = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("rp_data"));  

var obj = [];
for(var i = 0; i < info.data.length; i++){ 
var data = info.data[i];
obj.push({title : data[1], message : data[2], date : data[3]})
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))//this output is right
```

Ok so now the JSON.stringify(obj) is right, and now I want to display it in a new array:
So I tried with this:

```
 var html=(JSON.stringify(obj))

items:
    html
    ,
```

SOLVED, I just had to use the obj and not stringily it :-)

Comment: `var items = readcontent.map( ([ index, title, message, date ]) => ({ title, message, date }) );` #[tag:arrow-functions] #array-destructuring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution with multiple arrays.

```
var tmp = {"data":[[0,"Post1","Text1","2016-12-16T11:01:00.000Z"] , [1,"Post1","Text2","2016-12-16T11:01:00.000Z"], [1,"Post1","Text3","2016-12-16T11:01:00.000Z"] ]};
var obj = [];
for(var i = 0; i < tmp.data.length; i++){ 
var data = tmp.data[i];
obj.push({title : data[1], message : data[2], date : data[3]})
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

The output is :

```
[{"title":"Post1","message":"Text1","date":"2016-12-16T11:01:00.000Z"},{"title":"Post1","message":"Text2","date":"2016-12-16T11:01:00.000Z"},{"title":"Post1","message":"Text3","date":"2016-12-16T11:01:00.000Z"}]
```

Comment: Thanks, Anish. Yes it works, the console has the right output. But how do I get it into my 3 code section? I will update my question now.